# Wrap multiple selected elements with a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select from the A tag to the br tag with jquery and wrap it with a div.

I'm a third party developer developing a chrome extension and i get this data to work with:

```
<div id="indiv" style="font-size: 12px">
    <a href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
    <br>

    <a href="/?side=profiles&id=39818"><span style="color: #800909">Ernest Ferdinand Solis</span></a> (21:09): content here
    <br>

    <a href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
    <br>

    <a href="/?side=profiles&id=39818"><span style="color: #800909">Ernest Ferdinand Solis</span></a> (21:09): content here
    <br>
</div>
```

as you see, every "post" is seperate with a in first and br at the end.

I've no clue on how I should even approach, i've tested some wild things like:

```
$("<div>").insertBefore("#indiv a");
$("</div>").insertAfter($("#indiv a").next().next());
```

Jquery append /div right after the div automatically..

How I want it to look like in the end:

```
<div id="indiv" style="font-size: 12px">
    <div>
      <a href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
      <br>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
      <br>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
      <br>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
      <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the top of my head.
Add the both elements class inner.
With Jquery like this:

```
$('#indiv div a').addClass('inner')
```

Do the same for br.

Or add the manually.

```
<a class="inner" href="/?side=profiles&id=60438"><span style="color: #2498E0">Esmeralda Angelseye</span></a> (21:12): content here
          <br class="inner">
```

And the wrapt them both.

```
$('.inner').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

Comment: Yeah, good thought! It selects nearly everything but the "content here" part that does sadly not have a tag..

Comment: can you add tag?